# Pass a JPanel class to the main class in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I need to pass a JPanel extending class to the main class.

Here is what I have so far:
Main class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class main {

    private gamePanel gamepanel = new gamePanel();

    public JPanel createContentPane(){
        // We create a bottom JPanel to place everything on.
        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();

        //We set the Layout Manager to null so we can manually place
        // the Panels.
        totalGUI.setLayout(null);

        //Now we create a new panel and add it to the bottom JPanel.

        totalGUI.add(gamepanel);



        totalGUI.setOpaque(true);
        return totalGUI;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] There's a JPanel in here! [=]");

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        main demo = new main();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

        //The other bits and pieces that make your program a bit more stable.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a jog for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        System.out.println(gamepanel);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The gamePanel class

```
public class gamePanel extends JPanel implements Commons {

    private Dimension d;
    private ArrayList snowmens;
    private coreFunctions functions = new coreFunctions();
    private int snowmenX = 150;
    private int snowmenY = 5;
    private final String snowmenpix = "snowman.png";
    private JPanel background;

public gamePanel() {



    add(new JLabel("TEST"));
    setFocusable(true);


    setDoubleBuffered(true);
}


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 700, 700);



}
}
```

I can't figure out why the blue background and the label is not being shown...

EDIT:

Here are more details:

Ok so I am trying to make a little 2D game. For that I need to create some snowmen on the gamePanel class and display it via the main class. To start it off, the createContentPane creates a background panel, the root panel if you want. The createandshowgui creates a JFrame.

The gamepanel class is in fact a JPanel which has 1 panel as of now, which is the background panel. For now, I only want it to have a blue background.

I tried putting it like this because I saw some examples and they were pretty similar to what I have, but for some reason, I can't get it to work....

Thank you,
Ara

Comment: Your question is [especially vague](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and lacks needed information. Please specify technologies, intent, expected results and some attempt at your problem.

Comment: I added more details. Hope there is enough infos now...

Comment: wow great improvement on the accept rating, 100% now :)

Comment: I forgot to chose the answers. Thanks for making me remember :)

Comment: 1+ up-vote for trying to improve your question by supplying more information. Thanks. 1+ to @DavidK's answer.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `LayoutManager` instead of `setLayout(null);` and if only one component is being added no need for it either (that component will stretch to fill unless others are added)

see here for tutorial on `LayoutManager`s:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

If all you are trying to do is have a blue background (on which you can add components) then simply override `paintComponent()` of your `gamePanel` and paint the background blue:

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    }
```

then you can add your `JLabel` as if it was a normal Panel as the background is now being painted blue and not set by/as a component.

If you have an image look into `g.drawImage(Image image,int x,int y,ImageObserver iO)`

EDIT

DROP THE CALL TO:

`setLayout(null);`

and it will work

Comment: Also, double buffer is enabled by default ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I never knew hat! +1

Comment: The default layout for a `JPanel` is a `FlowLayout` which is supposed to append the elements horizontally. So for me, the second item should be at the `background`'s right. What I suspect here is that since the `background` panel doesn't have a preferred size, it's rendered with width = 0, regardless of the size set...

Comment: I tried removing the new Jlabel and it still doesnt work... and I also added a set preffered size without any luck...

Comment: @user1049769 It still doesnt work because what I told you to do is override `paintComponent()` you overrode paint()? and unless you are setting your `JPanel` to transparent drop the call to `setOpaque` in your main class, and that `setLayout(null)`. see edited post

Comment: @user1049769 note your call to 'setOpaque` does not make it transparent, but by default opaque is true, so that call is redundant